# How to get DPI device to PCL in Xamarin. Forms? - Followup

Tags: forms, xamarin, dpi

Using Xamarin Forms Visual Studio 2019.

I need to get the DPI of the device.

This post has a solution:
[How to get DPI device to PCL in Xamarin. Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53335001/how-to-get-dpi-device-to-pcl-in-xamarin-forms)

Implementing the solution gave problems:

When applying the answer above I get this error message:

> The type or namespace name 'DependencyAttribute' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In your android implementation, add a new class:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DisplayInfo))]
namespace .....
```

--I solved this compiler problem by replacing with:
using `Xamarin.Essentials`;

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(DisplayInfo))]
```

However when I compile and run the code, it falls over when I try consume this in the Xamarin Core Code:

```
int dpi = DependencyService.Get<IDisplayInfo>().GetDisplayDpi();
```

I get this runtime error on the above line:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

Any ideas? I would have added this question as a comment on the original, but as a new user do not have the points to do this... If someone could drop a comment on the original question's solution pointing it to this URL that would be helpful too.

Comment: You need to use like this:
int dpi = DependencyService.Get<YOUR_INTERFACE>().GetDisplayDpi();

Comment: have you followed the solution correctly? from what i have seen, it's: int dpi = DependencyService.Get<IDisplayInfo>().GetDisplayDpi(); you need to create an Interface in PCL, then implement it in the platforms. and that way, you are able to get the dpi

Comment: I did do this: DependencyService.Get<YOUR_INTERFACE>().GetDisplayDpi(); – it seems Stackoverflow did not like the < tag inside a question!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to my own question:

The solution original offered said do this:

In your android implementation, add a new class:

```
  [assembly: Dependency(typeof(DisplayInfo))]
  namespace YourAppNamespace.Droid
  {
     public class DisplayInfo : IDisplayInfo
     {
         public int GetDisplayWidth()
         {
             (int)Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
         }

         public int GetDisplayHeight()
         {
            (int)Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
        }

         public int GetDisplayDpi()
        {
             (int)Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi;
        }
     }
 }
```

The problem I did not see anywhere in the Android code that initialised this class, and I was unsure how best to do this really.

So I followed guidance for implementing the interface directly in the Android MainActivity.cs file, and this worked.. The video I watched to help me on that is here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgcnYDb6cRQ&t=19s

Comment: That's not a very useful answer.  "I fixed it.  Watch this video" doesn't tell me **what** really fixed the problem.